# Double root folder vs single root folder

Tags: linux, bash

On my Linux box, in bash, I have access to a "double root" folder denoted  by two forward slashes:

```
tomas:~ $ cd /
tomas:/ $ ls
bin/ cdrom@ ...
tomas:/ $ cd //
tomas:// $ ls 
bin/ cdrom@ ...
```

The content of the folder and its subfolder is identical to the "normal" single slash root. The double slash does not go away when I access its subfolders. The annomaly does not repeat itself with three or more slashes; these are simple synonyms for the root:

```
tomas:// $ cd home/tomas
tomas://home/tomas $ cd ///
tomas:/ $ cd ////
tomas:/ $
```

What kindof place is it? Is it a bug? Can anyone explain the annomaly?

Comment: good question - i noticed the same behavior but never asked why this happens.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

From [Bash FAQ E10](http://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/FAQ):

> E10) Why does 'cd //' leave $PWD as '//'?
>
> POSIX.2, in its description of 'cd', says that *three* or more leading
>   slashes may be replaced with a single slash when canonicalizing the
>   current working directory.
>
> This is, I presume, for historical compatibility.  Certain versions of
>   Unix, and early network file systems, used paths of the form
>   //hostname/path to access 'path' on server 'hostname'.

Comment: Domain/OS is one such system.

Comment: The double slash thing is still used. It's part of the Universal (or Uniform; I can't seem to find a primary source) Naming Convention or UNC. It appears in Windows, Unix, and Linux. It happens to be the reason a double slash is used in URLs.

Answer (score 1):

"It's not a bug, it's a feature!"

You're still in the same root directory.  I don't know the origins of this, but suspect it may have something to do with building strings for absolute paths.  If anyone else knows for sure, pipe up.

Answer (score 0):

Multiple slashes are just ignored by the tools you have used and you are always getting to the same root folder.

Comment: So why does bash change /// into / while leaving // as is?

Answer (score 0):

Multiple slashes are treated as a single slash for pathname-resolution purposes.

What you're seeing in the shell prompt is an artifact of bash PS1 handling (see section "PROMPTING" in the bash manpage).

```
[root@linux /]# cd /    ; echo $PWD
/
[root@linux /]# cd //   ; echo $PWD
//
[root@linux //]# cd /// ; echo $PWD
/
[root@linux /]# cd //// ; echo $PWD
/
```

The result is only a matter of presentation; you're always in the same root directory. You can check this by looking at `/proc/$$/root`.

[edit]
Well I never knew this:
http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap04.html#tag_04_11
The meaning of "//" is left undefined by the standards, but "///" and more slashes are equivalent to "/".